# Representations of $\text{SL}(n,\mathbb{F}_p)$ and $\text{Sp}(2n,\mathbb{F}_p)$ whose dimensions are $p^k$

Tags: rt.representation-theory, finite-groups

I should preface this by saying that I am not a representation theorist, so I apologize if this can easily be found in standard sources (but sadly I cannot seem to extract it from any of the books I know of).

Let $p$ be a prime number.  What are all the irreducible representations (over $\mathbb{C}$) of  $\text{SL}(n,\mathbb{F}_p)$ and $\text{Sp}(2n,\mathbb{F}_p)$ whose dimensions are $p^k$ for some $k$?  There are the Steinberg representations, but I assume that there are also others.

I'm particularly interested in the symplectic group.

Comment: Try looking at Carter's *Finite groups of Lie type* - it discusses the Deligne-Lusztig theory for groups of Lie type in great detail. Email me if you want an e-copy.

Comment: Why on earth did someone down vote this question?  I've certainly looked at books on Deligne-Lusztig theory, but they do things in so much generality that I cannot extract the answer to this simple-minded question.

Comment: @Sarah: Your question is straightforward-looking, but I don't think a full answer exists (yet) without heavy reliance on the Deligne-Lusztig theory and especially Lusztig's later work.  The easiest thing to compute from the theory is the degree of a virtual Deligne-Lusztig character, but getting to the irreducible characters takes a lot more work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A full classification of such representations (and much more) can be found here:

> *Prime power degree representations of
>   quasi-simple groups* by Malle and Zalesskii

You can read this paper [here](http://www.uea.ac.uk//~h054/Malle-Z-2001.pdf). The main theorem implies that, apart from the Steinberg representation, there are no representations of this form.

Interestingly this is not the case if you allow quasisimple covers of such groups, for instance $2\cdot {\rm Sp}_6(2)$ has an irreducible complex representation of degree $2^9$.

As I mentioned in my comment, if you want to understand the theory of these representations then I would go to *Finite groups of Lie type* by Carter. I should also say that it's quite possible that the fact you seek can be proved more directly than via the full classification given by Malle and Zalesskii ... but I don't know enough of D-L theory to tell you how.

P.S. if anyone knows how to put the correct accent on Zalesskii's name, then I'd like to know how!

Comment: This is very helpful.  Thank you very much!

Comment: And the edit made it even more helpful.  Thanks again!

Comment: Well, there's also the trivial representation if you don't specify that $k\geq 1$...

Comment: Re the PS: I believe that the spelling of Zalesskii's name has fairly recently been changed to Zalesski due to some new convention (not sure about the accent).

Comment: To follow up Geoff's remark, the current transliteration in MathSciNet is A.E. Zalesski, while in his early publications the soft sound at the end is indicated by writing Zalesski\u{i} using the LaTeX command \u{i} at the end.  (Transliteration is an art, not a science, and gets quite complicated as well as sometimes political for Chinese names.)

Comment: @Nick: Pinning down the degrees seems to require most of the Deligne-Lusztig theory, combined with some of Lusztig's follow-up work.   Carter's book provides fairly complete details about degrees based on D-L theory just when the algebraic group has *connected* center, while the last chapter of Lusztig's 1984 monograph helps fill in the general case.   As Lehrer's early 1970s thesis work with Green showed, it's very delicate to restrict from general linear to special linear groups, and symplectic groups pose similar challenges.

Comment: To add a more precise bibliographic note on Malle and Zalesskii, their short paper *Prime power degree representations of quasi-simple groups* appeared in
Arch. Math. (Basel) 77 (2001), no. 6, 461–468.

Comment: Jim, Thanks for your comments. I'm slightly surprised that this answer can't be answered more directly - I thought that, in my ignorance, I was using a sledgehammer to crack a nut but perhaps not. And, Geoff, thanks for the info on Zalesski's name.